# Is each Javascript function of a webpage supposed to be defined in its own separate .js file?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a website as a personal project to learn my way around the DOM and javascript. After several hours of annoyance, I discovered that if I comment out a portion of my HTML ("Animated Landing Page" in the HTML below) that has a javascript function (the `btnEnter.addEventListener` sequence in the JS) tied to it, anything after that function in my .js file ceases to work (such as the `test.addEventListener` sequence in the JS). Am I supposed to be separating my javascript functions into their own individual files? At the moment, I want to stick with javascript solutions, as I'd like to grasp the details of javascript before moving on to jQuery. I've included my HTML and JS below:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<title>My Webpage</title>
<!-- Add Javascript for enabled browsers -->
<script>document.documentElement.className += " js";</script>
<!-- Latest Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Bootstrap optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest Bootstrap Javascript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Personal stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MyStyle.css">
</head>
<body>

<!-- Animated landing page -->
<div id="cover-image">
    <button id="entry-btn">Enter</button>
</div>

<!-- Main site -->
<!-- Banner -->
<h1 class="center-content" id="banner">Banner</h1>

<!-- Navigation bar -->
<nav class="nav-bar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav-list">
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li><a class="navbar-link" id="link1" href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li><a class="navbar-link" id="link2" href="#page1">Page 1</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li><a class="navbar-link" id="link3" href="#page2">Page 2</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li><a class="navbar-link" id="link4" href="#page3">Page 3</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<!-- Content -->
<div id="home">HOME</div>
<br/>
<div id="page1">PAGE1</div>
<br/>
<div id="page2">PAGE2</div>
<br/>
<div id="page3">PAGE3</div>

<!-- Personal JavaScript file -->   
<script src="MyScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
var btnEnter = document.getElementById("entry-btn");
var test = document.getElementById("link1");

btnEnter.addEventListener("click", coverFadeOut);

test.addEventListener("click", testFunc);

function coverFadeOut() {
    var coverimg = document.getElementById("cover-image");
    coverimg.classList.toggle("fadeout");
    coverimg.addEventListener("transitionend", setTimeout(coverHide, 1000), false);
}

function coverHide() {
    var coverimg = document.getElementById("cover-image");
    coverimg.classList.toggle("hide");
}

function testFunc(){
    alert("Test");
}
```

To clarify, I'm asking why my `testFunc` is not working when I comment out the HTML section "Animated Landing Page"?

Comment: Each function doesn't have to be in its own javascript file. Of course, as your code gets longer and longer, you may want to break it into logical pieces, which would create separate files as needed. However, we ought to have a discussion on polluting the global namespace, as your coding becomes more advanced...

Comment: You've probably commented it out wrongly, but you'll have to show us how you did it ?

Comment: No, you don't have to put *each function* in its own file.  If you have code which demonstrates a describable problem, we might be able to help with that.

Comment: when you hit an error in a script, the script stops executing at that point. you just need to add error checking in your code to handle things missing or not being on the DOM. breaking up the script into smaller chunks would just mask your lack of error checking in this case and wouldn't really help the underlying issue of no null/undefined checks.

Comment: So if commented out that HTML part, javascript can't grt that element, so moves yo next function. Javascript works synchronously, line by line,

Comment: Note that the behavior you describe is demonstrably not reproducible: https://jsfiddle.net/p7fxwspx/  I've commented out the line you indicate, and the functionality you claim stops working still works.

Comment: @David I apologize if I wasn't clear. I commented out the HTML (not the JS) for the animated landing page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select an element you need to make sure it's not `undefined` before doing something with it. Your javascript will break if you try to access a method or property on `undefined` (in this case the method `addEventListener`).

```
var btnEnter = document.getElementById("entry-btn");
var test = document.getElementById("link1");

if (btnEnter) {
    btnEnter.addEventListener("click", coverFadeOut);
}

if (test) {
    test.addEventListener("click", testFunc);
}
```

Comment: That was exactly it. Thank you for providing an actual answer despite it being seemingly trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the Wonderful World of JavaScript!

I'd suggest hitting F12 in your browser and taking advantage of your browser's console and developer tools. They'll show you any exceptions that occur when your code runs. In your case, commenting out that button will cause one: by removing `entry-btn` from your page's markup, the code that adds an event listener to it will fail as `document.getElementById("entry-btn")` will return `null`.

```
var btnEnter = document.getElementById("entry-btn"); // Uh oh! This is gone! document.getElementById returns null.
btnEnter.addEventListener("click", coverFadeOut);    // btnEnter is null. I can't add a listener to it!
```

There's no need to add each function to a separate file. You just have to make sure that you're debugging while you're trying things out. (Incidentally, when it comes to grouping related files and functionality, you'd want to give the JavaScript Module Pattern or ES2015 modules a Google; they're the preferred way of keeping related pieces of code together).

Comment: Thank you for actually answering the question and proving additional help! I actually can't believe I missed this. I guess I just thought it would fail to perform that particular function and move on, not just break entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, it's not necessary to separate each js function into different files, but for big applications it is convenient, it favour code reuse, testing, etc

This is broad topic and depends greatly on team conventions, best practices and design patterns.

For example, the way I see it, javascript functions must be separated following concepts souch as encapsulation and abstraction, i.e: modules should have only one reason of change and must handle specific responsibilities.

You can decide to separate your functions into modules (aka: separate js files) following this concept. So for example, you can have a navigation file handling all functions specific to navigation, and other modules abstracting another aspects of functionality.

Hope it helped!